# WPF DataGrid: filter in header like in excel

Tags: xml, wpf, filter, datagrid

Is there a simple and free control which I can integrate in my XML code for an easy filter-posibility like in excel?

[image]

I found some controls on the web but the companies want to have like 2000$ a year for using their solution (telerik, syncfusion, etc.)... Also the free version of xceed toolkit (controls-package) doesnt support it.

Otherwise I would implement a dozen of textboxes above for filtering each column.. :-/

Comment: I don't know any of such control, though I believe it's not that difficult to implement such filtering yourself. Generating checkboxes for all unique values in a data grid column is a one-liner with Linq. And then filtering is already provided by Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar filter implementation on [code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering).

It is using the CollectionViewSource filtering of WPF and displays a filter input field based on the type of the bound value.

**Edit** - Link corrected

Comment: Thank you very much I ll try it :)